# Quickly inserting a separator line before and a column after in an org-table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

It's quite easy to enter an `org-table` in `org-mode` in Emacs.

One simply types `|Name|Phone|` <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```
| Name | Phone |
|      |       |
```

#### Inserting a separator line before

It's also easy enough to insert a separator line after a row
using <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> (`org-ctrl-c-minus`).

```
| Name | Phone |
|------+-------|
|      |       |
|------+-------|
```

Is the long dance

- <kbd>C-o</kbd> (`org-open-line`)
- <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> (`org-ctrl-c-minus`)
- <kbd>M-S-up</kbd> (`org-shiftmetaup`)

the best I can do to insert a horizontal/separator line before a line?

```
|------+-------|
| Name | Phone |
|------+-------|
|      |       |
|------+-------|
```

#### Inserting a column after

Also, it's easy enough to insert a column before an existing column
using <kbd>M-S-right</kbd> (`org-shiftmetaright`).

```
|---+------+-------|
|   | Name | Phone |
|---+------+-------|
|   |      |       |
|---+------+-------|
```

Is the longer dance

- <kbd>M-S-right</kbd> (`org-shiftmetaright`).
- <kbd>M-right</kbd> (`org-metaright`)

```
|------+-------+---|
| Name | Phone |   |
|------+-------+---|
| Bob  |   123 |   |
|------+-------+---|
```

the best I can do to insert a column on the right of an existing (end) column?

Comment: For inserting a separator after a row, I usually do `<RET> | - <TAB>` as I am usually at the end of the row already (otherwise, prepend a `C-e`). For inserting a column on the right, I do `C-e M-S-<right>`.

Comment: For inserting a separator before a row, I usually just do `C-a RET <up> | - <TAB>` i.e. open an empty line (breaking the table temporarily), go up to the empty line and insert the separator as above (which fixes the table again). I cannot remember all the keybindings that Org mode provides for these things, so I resort to more primitive methods.

Comment: @NickD  Oh, that's interesting. So it's possible to mess up the alignment of the vertical lines temporarily, and `Tab` will still fix the table back to something sane.

Comment: Yes: it primarily moves to the next cell but it has the side effect of (re)formatting the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from:

```
| Name | Phone |
|      |       |
```

##### Insert a separator after a row

<kbd>C-e</kbd>
<kbd>RET</kbd>
<kbd>|</kbd>
<kbd>-</kbd>
<kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
| Name | Phone |
|------+-------|
|      |       |
```

##### Insert a column on the right

<kbd>C-e</kbd>
<kbd>M-S-</kbd>

```
| Name | Phone |   |
|      |       |   |
```

##### Insert a separator before a row

<kbd>C-a</kbd>
<kbd>RET</kbd>
<kbd>Up</kbd>
<kbd>|</kbd>
<kbd>-</kbd>
<kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
|------+-------|
| Name | Phone |
|      |       |
```

Credit for this answer: NickD